# Unsure how to block specific applications on my childs WIndows 10 machine using Microsoft Family settings

Tags: windows-10, vpn, microsoft-family-safety

I'm trying to prevent my child from running a VPN on his Windows 10 school computer - preferably during a specific time frame.

I was hoping to block specific .exe applications via the Microsoft Family settings. I've not been able to see/find the way to do this.

1. Can this be done?
2. How can I achieve this?

I understand that at any time the child can download *another* vpn software which has a different name/exe so it's a trying game of cat and mouse.

I also understand that with "proper parenting" this wouldn't be required but please lets leave "poor parenting" out of the conversation (there's context missing here, which I don't want to give details on).

As a struggling parent - any help would be really helpful and appreciated!

Comment: Instead of trying to blacklist specific applications.  You should use a proxy. Microsoft Family is the improper way to block the execution of an application.  You must use a group policy to accomplish that, and the block, is against specific applications unless you start talking about only allow specific applications.  Only allowing the execution of specific executable is very time consuming and extremely easy to screw up.  What you want cannot be done solely with Microsoft Family settings

Comment: A proxy on the childs machine?

Comment: A proxy for the machine in general.  Yes;  A proxy you have the ability to configure.  The use of a proxy, would allow you to, properly deny and allow specific traffic.

Comment: That's part of the problem though? the traffic for VPN's are not a specific TCP/UDP port, these days. many times VPN's go through HTTP/HTTPS now :/